# Change ''Login to post Topic'' Button into Login link Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, authentication

I would like to know how do i change the ''Login to post Topic'' GreyOut Button (That normally dont act as a button link), into ''Login to post Topic'' **Button link**.

I mean, i want that when Guest enters a forum he will see ''Login to post Topic'' Button link ,and he will be able to actually login by forward him to the "login page":

> http://example.com/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login

Now, i had some research and i found under:

**Look & Feel** -> **Search and Replace** -> **Search**:

```
test="isGuestPostTopicTop:|: ! $this->memberData['member_id']"
```

Found this (Twice in the same file):

```
<li class='disabled'><span><if test="isGuestPostTopicTop:|: ! $this->memberData['member_id']">
{$this->lang->words['forum_no_start_topic_guest']}<else />{$this->lang->words['forum_no_start_topic']}</if></span></li>
```

Now, i tryied some methods to convert that grey out "Button" into Login link, but all i got is this:

```
<li class='disabled'><span><if test="isGuestPostTopic:|: ! $this->memberData['member_id']">
<a href='{parse url="core&module=global&section=login" base="publicWithApp"}' rel='nofollow' accesskey='s'>
{$this->lang->words['forum_no_start_topic_guest']}<else />{$this->lang->words['forum_no_start_topic']}</if></span></a></li>
```

But when i click on that button as a guest it reffers me to none exisiting page:

> http://example.com/index.php?app=forums&core&module=global&section=login

How do i actually make that Button Link to forward to the correct login page?

Comment: i dont quite understand what your question is. why dont you change the url?

Comment: I want that the address will parse the url and after the guest login or register he will be forward to create a new topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're editing from, but this seems to be your problem:

```
<a href='{parse url="core&module=global&section=login" base="publicWithApp"}' rel='nofollow' accesskey='s'>
```

Notice the base is `publicWithApp` which likely appends the `app=forums` to your link. Try changing that to just `public` and change the url part to `app=core&module=global&section=login`.

Comment: How do i forward the user automaticlly to create new topic after login?